# Updating a parcelable Object that was delivered from previous Activity

Tags: android

I have an object `Book` that has a field `urlString`.
I transfer my `Book` from **Activity A** to **Activity B** via `Intent.putExtra()` and then from **Activity B** to **Activity C** the same way. Inside **Activity C**, I want to update `Book.urlString`, in a way that will also update the original reference from **Activity A**. Meaning, the next time I approach the **same** `Book` from **Activity A** - it will already have a value in the field `urlString`.

What is the right way to do that (**without making Book static**)?

Comment: there are many approaches. 1) Make Book static 2) store in to sqlite 3) create flag

Comment: I don't want to make Book static... Can you elaborate on "create flag" ?

Comment: on activity C set flag true, in on resume of activity A check flag == true then update your Book

Comment: I can use onActivityResult twice. I'm not sure about what you mean by flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the objects through intent it serialises it and every time on retrieval it creates a new object. So in Activity C you have a different object than Activity A and B, basically if you'll change urlString it won't reflect in Activity A or B.

There are many approaches to resolve this, I prefer using the Singleton approach which acts as Data Provider

```
public class DataProvider {
private static DataProvider ourInstance = new DataProvider();

public static DataProvider getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}

private DataProvider() {
}

private List<Book> books;

public List<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}

public Book getBookById(long id) {
    // WRITE YOUR LOGIC HERE TO RETRIEVE OBJECT
    return book;
}
```

to access your book object use below code (hoping you have way to differentiate book object i.e. I assumed book id)

```
DataProvider.getInstance().getBookById(YOUR_ID);
```

with this approach as you are referencing to the same object in all activities, whatever updates you'll do will reflect in others.

Comment: Amazing solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need o make your `Book` class as `static`.

or

You save it in `SharedPreferences` and read from the `SharedPreferences` in each `Activity`

Comment: @UFC Insider Use sharedpreferences then

Comment: I have thousands of Books, it's not applicable to save them all in sharedPreferences